# jQuery variable doesn't change outside of function

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm using the following code to show the sidebar when .sidebar-toggle is pressed, and hide the sidebar when #page is pressed.

Showing the sidebar works perfect, but it doesn't hide when #page is being pressed. It looks like the variable isn't set to 1 when the .sidebar-toggle has been clicked.

```
var state = 0;

if (state === 0) {
    $('.sidebar-toggle').click(function() {
        $('#page').animate({marginLeft: '230px'}, 400);
        state = 1;
    });
}

if (state === 1) {
    $('#sidebar').click(function() {
        $('#page').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 400);
        state = 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: It would trigger on .sidebar-toggle click, not #page click--right?  Can you include your relevant HTML?

Comment: the code just runs once. so the state === 1 will never be executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were forgetting to use the #page click.function  ... and the best way is to put the if inside the click.function ... Try this way

```
var state = 0;

$('.sidebar-toggle').click(function() {
    if (state===0) {    
        $('#page').animate({marginLeft: '230px'}, 400);
        state = 1;
    }    
});

$('#page').click(function() {
    if (state===1){
        $('#page').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 400);
        state = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be because this never executed

```
if (state === 1) {
    $('#sidebar').click(function() {
        $('#page').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 400);
        state = 0;
    });
}
```

Try this way -

```
var state = 0;
    $('.sidebar-toggle').click(function() {
       if (state === 0) {
        $('#page').animate({marginLeft: '230px'}, 400);
        state = 1;
       }
    });

    $('#page').click(function() {
       if (state === 1) {
        $('#page').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 400);
        state = 0;
       }
    });
```